# magento pagination numbers not working

Tags: php, magento, pagination, numbers

I am working on existing magento site, and this is my first magento development.

There is option for "Items per page", but no pagination shown.

I need to show pagination with numbers like 1,2,3,4... I have tried it by changing options from admin area Configuration -> General -> Design -> Pagination.

Also tried many other tricks found by googling, but with luck.

Can someone show me correct way to paginate my products, or provide useful link which help in pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link [Magento pagination](http://workingmagento.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/magento-custom-pagination.html)

**EDIT:**

Also you can configure some more options at: `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend`

Such as number of products to display per page etc.

Comment: seen this before, not what i need, i need 16 product 1 page after click to 2 then display to 16 to 32 not all product display.